# from time to time VS. every now and then

Tags: adverbial-phrases

Is it okay to use 'from time to time' and 'every now and then' interchangeably?

Any comment would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "Every now and then" is more colloquial than "from time to time".  We might find the latter in a legal document, for example, but never the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are. Refer [Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/time_1?q=time%20to%20time).

> from time to time = *sometimes, but not often* = [(every) now and then](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/every-now-and-then-again)

The example follows:

> *From time to time I still think of her.*